# How to deserialize child object into list of parent (ex, List<Parent>) based on values of xml nodes?

Tags: c#, deserialization

I have one XML file called VehicleInfo.
I want to deserialize VehicleInfo in List of Vehicle.
Now I have one base class called Vehicle and three derived class named as Car, Bike, Truck.
How to deserialize specific object of vehicle based on value of Vehicle node in xml.
(ex. if node value is Car than object of car should be stored in List of vehicle)

```xml
<Vehicles>
    <Vehicle>Car</Vehicle>
    <Vehicle>Bike</Vehicle>
    <Vehicle>Truck</Vehicle>
</Vehicles>
```

For example,

VehicleList class :

```
public class VehicleList
{
    List<Vehicle> lstVehicles = new List<Vehicle>();
}
```

Vehicle class :

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public string name = "Vehicle";
}
```

Car class :

```
public class Car : Vehicle
{
    public Car()
    {
        name = "Car";
    }
}
```

Bike class :

```
public class Bike : Vehicle
{
    public Bike()
    {
        name = "Bike";
    }
}
```

Truck class :

```
public class Truck : Vehicle
{
    public Truck()
    {
        name = "Truck";
    }
}
```

This Vehicle program is just example,

So, How can I deserialize specific object (Such as Car, Bike, or Truck) in List of Vehicle in VehicleList class based on value of node Vehicle.

Comment: Make sample and serialize to see structure before de-serializing.  You need to use the Include attribute.  See :

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! In order to get help, provide the structure of your classes too. The base and child classes (at least some basic fields of them)

Comment: What did you try ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code and results to serialize.  XML you cannot have an array as a root element.  So in this case it make sense to have two classes : Vehicles and Vehicle.  See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication107
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Vehicles vehicles = new Vehicles()
            {
                vehicles = new List<Vehicle>() {
                    new Car() { make = "BMW"},
                    new Bike() { make = "Buffalo"},
                    new Truck() { make = "MAC"}
                }
            };

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Vehicles));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, vehicles);

        }
    }

    public class Vehicles
    {
        [XmlElement("Vehicle")]
        public List<Vehicle> vehicles { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlInclude(typeof(Car))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(Bike))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(Truck))]
    public class Vehicle
    {
        public string make { get; set; }
    }
    public class Car : Vehicle
    {
    }
    public class Bike : Vehicle
    {
    }
    public class Truck : Vehicle
    {
    }
}
```

Here is results :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Vehicles xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Vehicle xsi:type="Car">
    <make>BMW</make>
  </Vehicle>
  <Vehicle xsi:type="Bike">
    <make>Buffalo</make>
  </Vehicle>
  <Vehicle xsi:type="Truck">
    <make>MAC</make>
  </Vehicle>
</Vehicles>
```

Comment: FYI, it can also be done with element-naming rather than via xsi:type - but either is valid (it really comes down to: what is it *meant* to be in the specific implementation)

Comment: This is program to serialize obect to xml but I want to deserialize xml content to list of object.

Comment: I just posted serialize data so you get the format of the xml file.  You can change code to de-serialize easily.  De-serialize will fail if the XML file doesn't match the class structures so I always recommend serialize first and then compare the serialize xml with you actual input xml to see if the structure matches.

Comment: @user8833423 to echo that: they're the same thing - by showing `XmlSerializer` *serializing* something to the intended format, that also means we've configured it to *deserialize* that same something - you just use `Deserialize(...)` rather than `Serialize(...)`

Comment: @jdweng Seems to be worked for my problem. Thank u all for help.

Answer (score 0):

`XmlSerializer` supports some kinds of inheritance modelling, but: it is based on the *elements*/*attributes*, not the actual values; I'm not aware of any API that would support what you want *from that data*, so you'll have to deserialize them as strings, and post-process them to what you want.

An example of something that *would* be possible is:

```xml
<Vehicles>
    <Car>...car things...</Car>
    <Bike>...bike things...</Bike>
    <Truck>...truck things...</Truck>
</Vehicles>
```

which can be achieved via:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlInclude(typeof(Car))] // technically you only need XmlInclude
[XmlInclude(typeof(Bike))] // if you're using xsi:type resolution
[XmlInclude(typeof(Truck))] // but... it doesn't hurt us here
public abstract class Vehicle { }

public class Car : Vehicle { }
public class Truck : Vehicle { }
public class Bike : Vehicle { }

[XmlRoot("Vehicles")]
public class MyRoot
{
    [XmlElement("Car", Type = typeof(Car))]
    [XmlElement("Truck", Type = typeof(Truck))]
    [XmlElement("Bike", Type = typeof(Bike))]
    public List<Vehicle> Items { get; } = new List<Vehicle>();
}
static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var root = new MyRoot
        {
            Items =
            {
                new Car(),
                new Bike(),
                new Truck(),
            }
        };
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyRoot));
        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");
        ser.Serialize(Console.Out, root, ns);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is going to be long...

You can play with this solution [.net-fiddle-here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WYpjGT)

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var root = new Vehicles
        {
            Items =
            {
                new Vehicle() { Name = "Car"},
                new Vehicle() { Name = "Truck"},
                new Vehicle() { Name = "Bike"}
            }
        };
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Vehicles));

        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        TextWriter stringWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, root);

        string xml = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());


        //Make XML
        var obj = root;
        var xmlString = obj.XmlSerializeToString();

        //Make Object with Direct Deserialization
        var vehicles = xmlString.XmlDeserializeFromString<Vehicles>();

        //Make polymorphic object from generic vehicles with some "logic"
        var polymorphicVehicles = new List<Vehicle>();  // ******  THIS is the collection you requested!!!! *********

        // itterate all vehicles
        foreach (var item in vehicles.Items)
        {
            // use json serialization, because casting Parent to Child is not acceptable
            var jsonVehicle = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);

            // depending on the Name of the vehicle, create a corresponding object
            switch (item.Name)
            {
                case "Car":
                    var aCar = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Car>(jsonVehicle);
                    polymorphicVehicles.Add(aCar);
                    break;
                case "Truck":
                    var aTruck = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Truck>(jsonVehicle);
                    polymorphicVehicles.Add(aTruck);
                    break;
                case "Bike":
                    var aBike = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Bike>(jsonVehicle);
                    polymorphicVehicles.Add(aBike);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }


        // this is just to print it out!
        var jsonPolymorphicVehicles = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(polymorphicVehicles);

        Console.WriteLine("XML:");
        Console.WriteLine(xml);

        Console.WriteLine("");

        Console.WriteLine("Polymorphic to jason");
        Console.WriteLine(jsonPolymorphicVehicles);

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Press key to exit!");
        Console.Read();
    }


}



public class Vehicle
{
    public string Name = "Vehicle";
}

public class Car : Vehicle
{
    public Car()
    {
        Name = "Car";
    }
}

public class Bike : Vehicle
{
    public Bike()
    {
        Name = "Bike";
    }
}

public class Truck : Vehicle
{
    public Truck()
    {
        Name = "Truck";
    }
}

public class Vehicles
{
    public List<Vehicle> Items { get; } = new List<Vehicle>();
}


public static class MyStaticClass
{
    public static T XmlDeserializeFromString<T>(this string objectData)
    {
        return (T)XmlDeserializeFromString(objectData, typeof(T));
    }

    public static string XmlSerializeToString(this object objectInstance)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(objectInstance.GetType());
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        using (TextWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, objectInstance);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static object XmlDeserializeFromString(this string objectData, Type type)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
        object result;

        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(objectData))
        {
            result = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```